# Using php in html to display images from within a folder

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use this so I can list all the pictures in a folder I have and then later use some CSS to make it look nice but this keeps showing

> '; } } ?>

where the image should be

```
<body>
<h1>Laughing out loud</h1>
<?php
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/');
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
         echo '<img src="images/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
    }
}
?>
<p>To</p>
</body>
```

Comment: So when you view the source in the browser you can see your PHP code?

Comment: Seems alright to me; you running this on a server?

Comment: I am running it on a lighttpd server on my iPad and when I view the page it shows '; } } ?>

Comment: @H4unt3r Have you installed/enabled php?  From what I can tell, it isn't by default.

Comment: Problem seems about quotes be sure change them with hand correct ones if you copy paste code from a web page. May look legit at your editor but maybe ascii codes differ.

Comment: @MahmutAliÖZKURAN I would agree there, if the quotes were 'special' quotes.. like, unicode characters.  But as it stands they appear fine, and I've noticed that when they are unicode characters, they carry over to SO.

Comment: I have php installed and it works because I can place the php code into a index.php and it runs perfectly

Comment: @H4unt3r I find it hard to believe you; if you did have php installed, the above would not print, but cause a php parse error.

Comment: It's installed on cydia it comes bundled with the lighttpd package I installed

Comment: @H4unt3r What's your config option for php?

Comment: @Daedalus that actually may be the problem I can't really tell tho https://db.tt/3isO2K8d

Comment: @H4unt3r I meant your lighttpd config file, the one where you specify how to handle .php file extensions.  As I already said, its disabled by default.

Comment: @Daedalus it's this https://db.tt/go4ITz6H and how does one enable it

Comment: @H4unt3r Given I don't know exactly what OS you have, please see [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialLighttpdAndPHP); if that doesn't have the required information, I'll keep searching.  Also see [here](https://code.google.com/p/cydia-ios-lighttpd-php-mysql-web-stack/wiki/IosLighttpdPhpMysql#Configuration_Files), and scroll down to the 'File: /etc/lighttpd/mod_fast-cgi-atv.conf' header.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm ios7 but based on the second link you posted to the site where I installed my server from everything is how it's supposed to be

Comment: Then I'm sorry, as I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DirectoryIterator Class to search for the contents inside a folder

Shows us all files and catalogues in directory except "." and "..".

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../yourfolder') as $fileInfo) {
     if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
     echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
 }

?>
```

Comment: It's not that the actual search part doesn't work if I put the php part of the code into a test.php and open it, it displays the images perfectly